# Use of unresolved identifier "scanQRCode"

Tags: swift

I created a project with tab bars in Obj-C XCode and then I just want import a barcode scanner app to my project. I got finally a error when i told myself "Yes it will work". Can you help to figure it out ?

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class Barcode: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

@IBOutlet var videoPreview: UIView!

var stringURL = String()

enum error: Error {
    case noCameraAvailable
    case videoInputInitFail
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    do{
        try scanQRCode() /* I take error message right here "Use unresolved identifier"*/
    }
    catch{
        print("Tarama Gerçekleşemedi!")
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection){
        if metadataObjects.count > 0 {
            let machineReadableCode = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
            if machineReadableCode.type == AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode {
                stringURL = machineReadableCode.stringValue!
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "openLink", sender: self)
            }
        }
    }

    func scanQRCode()
        throws {
        let avCaptureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        guard let avCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) else{
            print("Kamera Bulunamadı!")
            throw error.noCameraAvailable
        }
        guard let avCaptureInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: avCaptureDevice)
            else{
            print("Kameraya Erişilemedi!")
            throw error.videoInputInitFail
        }
        let avCaptureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
        avCaptureMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)

        avCaptureSession.addInput(avCaptureInput)
        avCaptureSession.addOutput(avCaptureMetadataOutput)

        avCaptureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]

        let avCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: avCaptureSession)
        avCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        avCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?.frame = videoPreview.bounds
        self.videoPreview.layer.addSublayer(avCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!)

        avCaptureSession.startRunning()
    }

    func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){

        if segue.identifier == "openLink"{
            let destination = segue.destination as! WebViewController
            destination.url = URL(string: stringURL)
        }

    }

}
```

}

My main ViewController classes are Obj-C but i created barcode.swift for barcode-tab. This error about it or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created that function within another function, `didReceiveMemoryWarning`. which you shouldn't.

Move `scanQRCode` and all other functions you have declared inside `didReceiveMemoryWarning` outside of it.

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning().
}

func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection){
    //...
}

func scanQRCode() throws {
    //...
}

func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
    //...
}
```

Comment: TY Sir, You helped me so much.